# Select 1st day of each user id in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

Trying to figure out away to get the expected output from the id and date columns. How do i select 1st days of each user id .. the formula i tried is this IF(A2=A1,(IF(B2>B1,FALSE))) but not getting the exact expected output. I want the following expected output provided below..

```
id      date             Expected output   
14135   10/31/2018       TRUE
14135   11/16/2018       FALSE
14135   11/21/2018       FALSE
14135   11/21/2018       FALSE
21346   12/06/2018       TRUE
21346   12/06/2018       TRUE
21346   12/21/2018       FALSE
21346   12/21/2018       FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following in E2 and copy down.  Adjust ranges to suite your data.

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$2:$B$9/($A$2:$A$9=A2),1)=B2
```

NOTE:  Aggregate performs array like operations within the function therefore avoid full column references within the AGGREGATE function.

Alternatively MINIF may be a function available on excel 2016, but I only have 2013.  MINIF if you have it is the better solution.

[image: POC]

Answer (score 1):

Here's the formula using MINIFS:

```
=MINIFS(B:B, A:A, A2) = B2
```

This returns the minimum value from column B for rows where column A is euqal to A2; it then does a check to see if the value in B2 is equal to this minimum.

Depending on the size of your spreadsheet you may want to make it more efficient by restricting the length of the arrays rather than keeping the entire column, something more like:

```
=MINIFS(B$2:B$9, A$2:A$9, A2) = B2
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using array formulas for this type of problem:

```
{=MIN(IF(C$6:C$13=C6,D$6:D$13,10000000))=D6}
```

You enter the equation without braces and press ctrl-shift-enter to add them. This generates an array of values, 10000000 if it does not equal the id and the date otherwise. It then calculates the minimum value and sees if that equals its row value.